# How can I deserialize multiple files and form data in a single request using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to desearialize a form with some basic form data + one or more uploaded files.

If I send the following request (generated as Python Requests code using Postman)

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/forms/test/"

payload = {
'customer_id': '123456789',
'customer_name': 'Billy Bob'}
files = [
  ('files', open('/C:/tmp/aaaaa.csv','rb')),
  ('files', open('/C:/tmp/bbbbb.csv','rb'))
]
headers= {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

The code returns the following response (I hoped it would save the file instead).

```
{
    "files": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Models

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models

class Mtfar(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer_id = models.IntegerField()
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)

class MtfarFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
    mtfar = models.ForeignKey(Mtfar, related_name='files', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Mtfar, MtfarFile

class MtfarFileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MtfarFile
        fields = ['file']

class MtfarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    files = MtfarFileSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Mtfar
        fields = ['customer_ptid', 'customer_name', 'files']
```

View

```
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, parser_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import MtfarSerializer, MtfarFileSerializer

@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser])
def post_generic_form(request):

    data = request.data
    
    filelist = []
    for f in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
        filelist.append({
            'file': f
        })
    data.setlist('files', filelist)

    serializer = MtfarSerializer(data=data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the ***`QueryDict`*** object into a ***`dict`*** to support ***nested serialization***, because DRF parsing the **`QueryDict`** in a different way. [(Ref: **`get_value(self, dictionary)`** method -- (DRF source code)](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/e17779c47bccd218cfcdf1f3eaa61c354032ff71/rest_framework/serializers.py#L402))

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser])
def post_generic_form(request):
    dict_data = {
        **request.data.dict(),
        **{"files": [{"file": file} for file in request.FILES.getlist('files')]}
    }
    serializer = MtfarSerializer(data=dict_data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: The app now responds with:

{
    "files": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."
        ]
    }
}

It also seems to only keep the second uploaded file (bbbbb.csv) with this dict type.